# Trying to understand SQL Server index recommendation

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing

I have a SQL query

```
UPDATE [Siberia].[dbo].[resources]
SET [D_MODIFY] = '2016-09-05',
    [ACTUAL] = 0,
    [CL_ACTUAL] = 0,
    [APPROVE] = 1,
    [REASON] = 6
WHERE 
    [ID_REGCOD] = 374652
    AND [ACTUAL] IN (1, 2);
```

When I run this query with the option "Include actual execution plan", the SQL adviser recommends creating this index

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [<Name of Missing Index, sysname,>]
ON [dbo].[resources] ([ID_REGCOD], [ACTUAL])
INCLUDE ([PK_REGCOD], [APPROVE])
GO
```

I want to understand why it recommends to include column `APPROVE`.

I understand why it uses columns `ID_Regcod, Actual`, and includes `PK_Regcode` (clustered index). But I don't get why it includes the column `APPROVE`.

Comment: I agree - doesn't make a lot of sense. For a `SELECT`, including `APPROVE` (but also `CL_ACTUAL` and `REASON`) could make sense to make this a "covering" index so that a `SELECT` could get all values required directly from the index and avoid going back to the actual data page. But for an `UPDATE`, that's moot. But the index recommendations in SSMS are notorious for not being very "spot on" at times - they will sometimes recommend creating an index that already exists - or like here be a bit "off" in what columns to include.

Comment: I think it alwyas suggests a covering index.

Comment: @xhr489: well - this recommended index **isn't** a covering index - so I believe your statement isn't correct

Comment: @marc_s, okay thanks, I don't have much experience with data modification execution plans but for selects it seems that it always suggests a covering index

Comment: @xhr489: that would definitely make a lot of sense, indeed. But this recommendation here seems to be a bit ... "off" .....

Comment: In any case, a covering index doesn't make much sense for an `update` query because the original data rows need to be locked and modified anyway.

Comment: At first, you have to look at all other indexes on that table.
You might already have an index on "ID_REGCOD", then you can just add "ACTUAL" to it.

Comment: Also, it depends on how often you run that kind of query. 
If you always use "[ACTUAL] IN (1, 2)" you can use it to create a filtered index.
In addition you do not need to include "PK_REGCOD" into the index. Reference to a clustered index is embedded automatically behind the seen.